# Is there a word for confusing words like 'everyday' with phrases like 'every day'?

Tags: terminology, compounds

I see people confusing words that are compounded from two words with a phrase made from those words. This is easy to do, as they look and sound very similar:

For example:

- "everyday", an adjective, with "every day", which I assume is a prepositional (or adverbial?) phrase.
- "giveaway", a noun, with "give away", a phrase containing a verb.
- "awhile", an adverb, with "a while", a noun phrase.

However, the word "everyday" has a defined meaning in Standard English, and it's different to "every day". My question assumes that the inevitable language change that leads to each pair merging hasn't happened yet.

Phenomena like this sometimes have specific names (like 'metathesis'). Is there a technical name given to this mixup?

Comment: You forgot "alot", I see that *spelling* mistake quite a bit. There ain't no confusion, in speech the words are being used correctly, it's how they are written down that create confusion or ambiguity.

Comment: I don't think "alot" counts, as it isn't a word in Standard English.  (It's a word on Reddit, but it's more of an inside meta joke word)

Comment: And I think there is confusion. "Giveaway" is pronounced differently to "give away", at least in my experience. Aaand even if there isn't cognitive confusion and it's a surface-level spelling error, this is still a phenomenon that could have a name.

Comment: If speakers want to say that something revealed its true identity they'll say: *"That was* ***a*** *real giveaway"* If they wrote it as "a real give away" then we're talking about a misspelling, it's incorrect, but the phrase is grammatical in speech. What about someone writing "some one"?

Comment: Indeed it might boil down to falsely perceived homonym when spelling. Whatever the mechanism (which is an interesting question), the question of terminology stands.

Answer (score 1):

Homophones

Whether it's two words or phrases, if their sound similarity is the problem, they are homophones.

See also egg-corns and mondegreens

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine a case where you would notice this misuse in speech. Rather you would notice it when viewing written words. I may be wrong but I'd bet good money all the examples you gave would sound exactly the same when spoken.

"Wait awhile" vs "Wait a while"
"Everyday is the same" vs "Every day is the same"
"I don't want to giveaway my secret" vs "I don't want to give away my secret"

In view of that, I'd simply call it a mispelling, an orthographic error or a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I believe *misusage* may fit here:

> - Improper application, as of words. [(The Free Dictionary)](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/misusage)

Comment: That's a bit broad. I'm enquiring whether there's a word as specific as, for example, metathesis.

Comment: I see you are not satisfied with the answer. It is absolutely understandable, but I think there is no such word. I hope someone more knowledgeable can help you soon (to the benefit of both of us, of course).

Comment: FYI, sometimes you need to edit your question so that more people see the question. sometimes it works.

Comment: Thanks, I'm experienced with stackoverflow but not this community. I've given it a little edit. Yeah, there probably isn't a specific word, but you never know!

Comment: You are right. English is something.